# JExcel doesn't copy Array formula

Tags: arrays, formula, jexcelapi

I open excel file by JExcel, modify some cells and save it.
As result Array formulas({ ... } CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) was broken.
Does anybody know what to do? (FormulaException is rasing during copy)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to use excel macros, which manually set squiggle brackets in formulas while opening excel file.